# Any public transport from Tauranga airport to the city?

Tags: public-transport, airport-transfer, new-zealand

Aside from taxis, is there any public (bus etc) transport from the Tauranga airport to the downtown area?

And if so, are there online timetables available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two bus routes than run on Hewletts Rd which is pretty close to the airport:
[No.1](http://www.baybus.co.nz/routes/tauranga/tauranga-route-1-pyes-pa-city-mount.aspx) and [No.33](http://www.baybus.co.nz/routes/Tauranga/Tauranga-Route-33-City-Bayfair-Papamoa.aspx). For routes, fares and timetables follow the links.

Downtown and the beach are not that far from the airport, so unless you have lots of luggage you could also just walk.